# How to get base url in a layout xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

I'm using Magento 1.9 and in *app/design/frontend/mytheme/mytheme/layout/page.xml* I got the following code snippet:

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="core/text" name="stylescss">
    <action method="setText">
        <css><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/css/styles.css?v=1.0" media="all" />]]></css>
    </action>
</block>
```

This was done originally in order to be able to control the version of the stylesheet, and bypass several layers of caching, forcing the user browser to fetch a different version of the file.

**Is there a way to replace www.example.com for a variable containing the baseurl?**

P.S. Any alternative solution to add versioning to a file, is more than welcome :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use use helper method.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="stylescss">
        <action method="setText">
            <css helper="your_module/someHelperMethod" />
    </action>
</block>
```

And then, in your module helper file, create method, which return string with base url.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried using: `module_namespace/helperMethod` and Magento is adding Mage_ in front of my Helper class name. What am I missing?

Comment: I was using the wrong helper path. I changed to modulename/helperMethod and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!